# Cannot find class [org. nspringframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have added the following jars as attached in the image, but still I am getting the below exception. I am not able to figure out where is the problem. I tried opening jars and checking and found that the class is present. But still I am getting this exception. Please help.Please find the exception and jars attached in the image.
[image]

Comment: 1. Please show us your code. 2. HibernateTemplate is deprecated and has been removed from current Spring versions. What version are you using?

Comment: Thanks Sean Patrik Floyd.. Spring 3.0 and above. I have many classes being used. Controller,Dao, Model, businesss, which all codes you want ? I think it's jar problem.

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled the class: [org. nspringframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate]

it should be org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate

Comment: It was coming in exception so, I added the same.

Comment: This certainly looks like the key to me. Somewhere in your config you mis-typed the class name. Class names should not have spaces!

Answer (score 0):

There was some silly mistake in the code. I just figured it out. Have corrected the issue. It was in the hibernate configuration xml file. Thanks all for their answers.